# extern keyword behavior with Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, variables, extern

I had created this minimal example to illustrate my problem with extern declaration with Visual Studio 2008 (required to compile a python 2.7 extension). The same example is working well with gcc.
The result is that I have 2 separate global_var variables instead of a unique one in lib.c

the library interface : lib.h

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H 1

int __declspec( dllexport ) displayGlob();

#endif // LIB_H
```

the library code

```
// lib.c
#include<stdio.h>

int global_var=2;

int __declspec( dllexport ) displayGlob() {
    printf("lib.c global_var=%d\n", global_var);
    return global_var;
}
```

the user code that uses the library variable "global_var" and function displayGlob()

```
// main.c

#include"lib.h" 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

extern int global_var=0; // must be initialized otherwise "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol global_var"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  printf("main.c global_var=%d\n", global_var);
  displayGlob();
  global_var = 3;
  printf("main.c global_var=%d\n", global_var);
  displayGlob();
  exit(0);
}
```

execution result is:

```
main.c global_var=0
lib.c global_var=2
main.c global_var=3
lib.c global_var=2
```

Questions:

1 - Why must I initialize the extern variable in lib.h with Visual Studio and not Gcc ?

2 - Why the global_var lib.c displayed by the second displayGlob() is not modified to 3 ?

thanks for any hint !

Laurent

UPDATE: moved extern declaration of global_var from lib.h to main.c (even simpler example)
and of course problems remain...

Comment: Yes, you have two global variables.  One in the DLL, another in the EXE.  Don't do that.

Comment: In the .c file, either mark the variable `extern` or include the header. Also, you almost never want to define a variable in a header (so remove the initialization).

Comment: the header (and extern declaration of global_var) is already included in main.c. If I do not initialize the extern, I have a LINK error

Answer (score 0):

Because C preprocesor basically pastes the content when you call `#include`, it the same as you declared your `extern` inside of `main.c` file. This means that this symbol is defined twice (in `main.c` and in `lib.c`).

What you should do is to add `extern` declaration to `lib.c` (for example by including `lib.h`) and initialize the value there, then remove initialization from `lib.h`.

So it should be like this:

lib.h:

```
extern global_var;
```

lib.c:

```
#include "lib.h"
int global_var=2;
```

main.c

```
#include "lib.h"
(no global_var definition/declaration here)
```

Comment: extern in .c file is not a good idea. Extern is not a definition, its only a declaration. Therefore, it can be used more than once in one file.

Comment: You are right, `extern` should not be used with definition, it can only be used with declaration.

Comment: When adding lib.h in lib.c (I already tried before asking) I have a redefinition error: 
1>.\lib.c(7) : error C2374: 'global_var' : redefinition; multiple initialization
1>        vs2008\main\lib.h(4) : see declaration of 'global_var'

Comment: @Iclevy: You did something wrong. As your error message says, you have two definitions of `global_var` while you should only have one - in `lib.c`. Then, you should have multiple declarations of `global_var` with `extern` keyword - one in each file that is using this variable. See my updated answer.

Comment: applying your suggestions: with "extern int global_var;" included in main.c via lib.h, I have "main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol global_var"

Comment: @Iclevy: I don't know how Visual Studio works but are you sure that lib.c is added to the project? Is it compiled at all?

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself, my fault.

Under Gcc I built both a static library and a dynamic library. My main.c was linked with the STATIC library, so variable resolution between lib.c and main.c was resolved at link time. I forgot that.

Under Visual Studio, I only built a DYNAMIC library, so it was normal variable linkage could not happen between the DLL and main.o

Sorry for any confusion created...